# C# HidLibrary - USB HID

Tags: c#, usb, hid, libusb

[image][image]I'm attempting to emulate communication with a device connected via USB/HID and its accompanying software. So far, I've managed to replicate the message flow up to obtaining the descriptor and serial number. However, I'm a bit unsure about the next piece of code. I've employed a device monitoring tool to analyze the data exchanged by the Windows application that accompanies the device, and I've hit a roadblock at this specific juncture. I'm hoping someone could lend a hand with this.

Thanks!

[image]

some c# examples or guidance , i don't mind using other libraries too.